# how to use nodejs crypto module in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-crypto

Is there any way i can use nodejs "crypto" module in javascript without actually using node.

Or is there any similar javascript library that does all the things that "crypto" does

Like i neeed the below code in javascript with the help of nodejs

```
  var crypto = require('crypto'),
     hash = crypto.createHash('sha256'),
     hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', someKey);
```

**basically i need to replicate below in javascript without using node at all**

```
var bytesToSign = hash.update(stringToSign).digest();
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to use the crypto module but not node? If it's JS based encryption you're looking for then there are other choices available.

Answer (score 1):

node.js crypto module is based on openssl library

you can try [this](http://www.bichlmeier.info/sha256.html) native js implementation of sha256 digest

Comment: basically i need to replicate below in javascript without using node at all   "var bytesToSign = hash.update(stringToSign).digest();". Not sure how to do this without using node

Comment: with the mentioned script its just `digest = sha256_digest(stringToSign)`, no node dependency